# Flickity complete event when initialized with HTML

Tags: flickity

Is there an event that I can listen to, when Flickity has finished initialization?

When initializing with JavaScript, I can trigger an event by myself, but by using this setup I have no clue.

**Initialize with HTML**
http://flickity.metafizzy.co/#initialize-with-html

```
<div data-flickity='{ … }'>
  …
</div>
```

Currently, I am checking if Flickity has generated it's DOM elements, but that is not very elegant. :-)

Comment: did you find something for this?

Comment: Nothing new to tell

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Flickity.prototype.on( 'activate',function(){
alert("active")});

```js
Flickity.prototype.on( 'activate',function(){
alert("active")});
```

```css
/* external css: flickity.css */

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.carousel {
  background: #EEE;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #8C8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  counter-increment: gallery-cell;
}

/* cell number */
.carousel-cell:before {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: counter(gallery-cell);
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js"></script>
<!-- Flickity HTML init -->
<div class="carousel" id="carousel" data-flickity>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>
```